# Why XML serializer returns null on object deserialization with namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have this case:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Response
    {
        public string RetKey { get; set; }
        public string RetType { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test3()
    {
        {
            var s = @"<Response  CommandID=""57b48ae28f484ab4b3cc2e841cddd02a"">
    <RetKey>5</RetKey>
    <RetType>152</RetType>
    </Response>";

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
            var deserialize = (Response)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(s));

            Assert.AreEqual("5", deserialize.RetKey, "no namespace");
        }

        {
            var s = @"<Response xmlns=""http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS"" CommandID=""57b48ae28f484ab4b3cc2e841cddd02a"">
    <RetKey>5</RetKey>
    <RetType>152</RetType>
    </Response>";

            var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute
            {
                ElementName = typeof(Response).Name,
                Namespace = "http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS",
                IsNullable = true
            };

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response), xRoot);
            var deserialize = (Response)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(s));

            Assert.AreEqual("5", deserialize.RetKey, "try to declare namespaces");
        }
    }
```

Which fails on second try (with namespaces). 
So I'm in stuck with correct using namespaces in xml deserialization.
What confuses me, that deserialization proceed without errors, but returns empty object.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The xml for the second version is **completely different**, so it is correct that it fails. Namespace is *fundamental* to the identity of an xml node. If you want the second version to work, you'd need to tell it that `Namespace="http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS"` in all the relevant `[Xml...]` attributes, noting that `xmlns="..."` is inherited by sub-elements. Which means you also need to tell it that `RetKey` and `RetType` are in that namespace.

If you want to define this at runtime, then:

```
var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute
{
    ElementName = nameof(Response),
    Namespace = "http://www.sap.com/SBO/DIS",
    IsNullable = true
};
var xor = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
xor.Add(typeof(Response), nameof(Response.RetKey), new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute(nameof(Response.RetKey))
        { Namespace = xRoot.Namespace } }
});
xor.Add(typeof(Response), nameof(Response.RetType), new XmlAttributes
{
    XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute(nameof(Response.RetType))
        { Namespace = xRoot.Namespace } }
});
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response),
    xor, Type.EmptyTypes, xRoot, xRoot.Namespace);
```

However, note that when you create an `XmlSerializer` in this way, you **must** cache and reuse it - it generates a new assembly *every time you `new XmlSerializer(...)`* like this, which gets very expensive very quickly. So: store it somewhere! Or just use attributes (it caches internally when using the simple constructor).